# Fake javax.mail.Session

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I have an application that sends emails. But in my development environment, I don't want the application to send email, rather it should only print the message in log file.

There are a fake `javax.mail.Session` implementation that I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this problem I would use a custom `javax.mail.Transport` which is registered to the SMTP protocol.

First implement the CustomTransport class

```
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.*;

public class CustomTransport extends Transport {

  public CustomTransport(Session smtpSession, URLName urlName) {
    super(smtpSession, urlName);
  }

  @Override
  public void sendMessage(Message message, Address[] addresses) throws MessagingException {
    // Take the message and write it somewhere
    // e.g.: a logger or an OutputStream message.writeTo(...);
  }

  @Override
  public void connect() throws MessagingException {}

  @Override
  public void connect(String host, int port, String username, String password) throws MessagingException {}

  @Override
  public void connect(String host, String username, String password) throws MessagingException {}

  @Override
  public void close() {}
}
```

Afterwards you can use that CustomTransport to create a `javax.mail.Session` which writes your mails to the defined location

```
public Session getMailSession(){
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
  props.put("mail.smtp.provider.class", CustomTransport.class.getName());
  props.put("mail.smtp.provider.vendor", "foo");
  props.put("mail.smtp.provider.version", "0.0.0");

  return Session.getInstance(props);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to configure your local **Tomcat** installation to use a fake `Transport` implementation,

The Session implementation seems to only load configuration from home lib folder and classpath META-INF/javamail.providers, see [Session](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Session.html) javadoc.

If you configure you mail session with **Tomcat JNDI**, just copy an additional JAR file with one file `META-INF/javamail.providers` to Tomcat lib folder:

```
$ mkdir META-INF
$ echo 'protocol=smtp; type=transport; class=CustomTransport;' > META-INF/javamail.providers
$ jar cf custom-transport.jar META-INF
$ cp custom-transport.jar $TOMCAT/lib/
```

You can put the above class `CustomTransport` into the same Jar or anywhere in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you are asking for, but [GreenMail](http://www.icegreen.com/greenmail/) is a test implementation of SMTP, POP3 and IMAP protocol. You can start GreenMail server from JUnit and query received e-mails. This way you are exercising the whole stack, but `javax.mail` uses fake server running on `localhost` on some arbitrary port.

The library is available in maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.icegreen</groupId>
    <artifactId>greenmail</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1b</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Not exactly. I think in a API similar to Google App Engine email that runs on local server. In your code, you uses Java Mail Session, but instead to send the email, this implementation only print the email in console, and not send the email. Thank you.